# F# deedle cast column datatype

Tags: f#, deedle

I have load a `csv` file to a `Frame`, `deedle` automatically infers that one column as `decimal`, whichi in fact should be `int`.

I have use the following line to do the casting into the correct type,

```
df?ColumnName <- df.GetColumn<int>("ColumnName")
```

I am wondering if this is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control the type of columns when reading .csv.

ReadCsv(...) has such parameter as schema:

> schema - A string that specifies CSV schema. See the documentation for
>   information about the schema format.

More information can be found [here](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/CsvProvider.html) (in the section Controlling the column types)

Example:

.csv:

```
Name,Age,Comp1,Comp2
"Joe", 51, 12.1, 20.3
"Tomas", 28, 1.1, 29.3
"Eve", 2, 2.1, 40.3
"Suzanne", 15, 12.4, 26.3
```

F#:

```
let pathToCSV = "0.csv"
let schema = "Name,Age(int),Comp1,Comp2"

let loadFrame = Frame.ReadCsv(pathToCSV, schema=schema)
loadFrame.Format() |> printfn "%s"

loadFrame.ColumnTypes |> Seq.iter(printfn "%A")
```

Print:

```
     Name    Age Comp1 Comp2
0 -> Joe     51  12,1  20,3
1 -> Tomas   28  1,1   29,3
2 -> Eve     2   2,1   40,3
3 -> Suzanne 15  12,4  26,3

System.String
System.Int32
System.Decimal
System.Decimal
```

Although, for me, Frame have the correct column types and without specifying the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Well if it works for you..., this gets the column and overwrites with the type specified.

You have another option, which is to specify the schema of the CSV file:

> •inferTypes - Specifies whether the method should attempt to infer
> types of columns automatically (set this to false if you want to
> specify schema)
>
> •inferRows - If inferTypes=true, this parameter
> specifies the number of rows to use for type inference. The default
> value is 0, meaning all rows.
>
> •schema - A string that specifies CSV
> schema. See the documentation for information about the schema format.

You could probably check the CSV type provider docs for ReadCsv.